# getting argument is of length zero error in tensorflow and R

Tags: r, tensorflow

I have created an R application and i have load an deep learning model which i have created on kaggle and now using on windows pc but everytime i load this model i get this error.

```
Error in if (tensorflow::tf_version() < "2.0.0") stop("TensorFlow version >= 2.0.0 is requires to load models in the SavedModel format.",  : 
  argument is of length zero
```

this model is able to load on kaggle but getting error on my windows PC can someone tell me what could be wrong in my PC

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.